# @Observable not working exactly as required

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am stuck in a problem while using @Observable. I am using it to format a textfield for credit card. I created a textfield formatter and a custom textfield using a lengthy code that I have uploaded in a gist: https://gist.github.com/amrit42087/98750b2e22b299368b07ed6e78d530a8

The below code is using for creating the UI:

```
import SwiftUI

  struct Person: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID()
  var name: String
  var age: Int
}

struct View1: View {
  @ObservedObject var personVM = PersonViewModel()

  var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                CreditCardTextfield()
                    .offset(y: 100)
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()

        }
        .onAppear {
            self.personVM.addPerson()
        }
    }
}
}

struct CreditCardTextfield: View {
   @ObservedObject var cardFormatter = TextFieldFormatter(limit: 19, type: .cardNumber)
   @State var isFirstResponder = false

   var body: some View {
        CustomTextField(text: $cardFormatter.text, isFirstResponder: $isFirstResponder, placeholder: "XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX", font: .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold), keyboardType: .numberPad)
            .frame(height: 40)
  }
}

class PersonViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var people: [Person] = []

func addPerson() {
    people.append(Person(name: "Test", age: (0...30).randomElement() ?? 0))
}
}
```

The problem is that formatter does not work if I use this line self.personVM.addPerson() in onAppear(). Commenting out this line eradicates the problem. I just need to understand the reason behind this issue. Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: What does "formatter does not work" exactly mean?  Give details about what you expect and what actually happened.

Comment: How many of `CreditCardTextfield` in your screen of view hierarchy?

Comment: @LouFranco, "formatter does not work", means that the TextFieldFormatter() that expects the credit card number like "4111111111111111" to be formatted as "4111 1111 1111 1111" does work. In addition to card formatter we can also use it as expiry date formatter. But here I am using it just for credit card formatting.

Comment: @Asperi, there is only one CreditCardTextfield in view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make `CreditCardTextfield` equatable, so it won't recreate on personVM update.

```
struct CreditCardTextfield: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: CreditCardTextfield, rhs: CreditCardTextfield) -> Bool {
        true
    }

    // ... other code here
```

and in usage place

```
VStack {
    CreditCardTextfield().equatable()
        .offset(y: 100)
    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: Wonderful!! You have done the magic. I was relatively new to swiftUI. Can you let me know why recreation of the CreditCardTextfield restricts it from working? I mean, even if its recreated on personVM, it should be listening to the changes? I am sorry, I even doubt my question but will be great if you shed a little light on to it.

Answer (score 0):

Views are copied and created a lot -- every time the view changes, you are constructing a new version. So you don't want code like this in a View

```
@ObservedObject var personVM = PersonViewModel()
```

That will create a brand new view model every time the view changes.  So, adding a person to the view, adds it to the view model and then makes a new view with an empty view model.

You want to construct it outside of the view and pass it into the init.  The future View values will copy it from the property (not recall that init).  So, use:

```
@ObservedObject var personVM: PersonViewModel
```

And make View1 like this

```
View1(personVM: personViewModel) // personViewModel was constructed beforehand
```

Be careful constructing it there too -- because that line is in a View struct as well, and will keep constructing the view model.

Comment: Hi @LouFranco, you are correct and I am already aware of this thing and its consequences. And also the formatter works if passed from the previous view but I doubt if its a good practice to declare all the similar view models before hand and passing them to the destination view. Also, I am still unable to understand that why multiple new versions of PersonViewModel() would not let the TextFieldFormatter() to work as expected.

Comment: What is expected? What is it doing?

Comment: "formatter does not work", means that the TextFieldFormatter() that expects the credit card number like "4111111111111111" to be formatted as "4111 1111 1111 1111" does work. In addition to card formatter we can also use it as expiry date formatter. But here I am using it just for credit card formatting.